# Join CSV with different columns

Tags: python, csv, join, merge

I have a problem:

I have two CSV files

Here is the content of CSV1:

```
Switch,Switchport Number,Port Name,VLAN
TEST-SWITCH,1,TEST PORT 1,20
TEST-SWITCH,2,DEVICE 1,20
TEST-SWITCH,3,TEST PORT 2,20
TEST-SWITCH,4,DEVICE 2,20
TEST-SWITCH,5,TEST PORT 3,20
TEST-SWITCH,6,DEVICE 3,20
TEST-SWITCH,7,OFFICE,20
TEST-SWITCH,8,FREE,20
TEST-SWITCH,9,THIN CLIENT,20
TEST-SWITCH,10,PRINTER,20
TEST-SWITCH,11,COUNTER 1,20
TEST-SWITCH,12,COUNTER 2,20
TEST-SWITCH,13,FREE,20
TEST-SWITCH,14,FREE,20
TEST-SWITCH,15,FREE,10
TEST-SWITCH,16,FREE,10
TEST-SWITCH,17,MUSIC PLAYER,10
TEST-SWITCH,18,VIDEO PLAYER,10
TEST-SWITCH,19,ALARM,10
TEST-SWITCH,20,AP1,99
TEST-SWITCH,21,AP2,99
TEST-SWITCH,22,AP3,99
TEST-SWITCH,23,AP4,99
TEST-SWITCH,24,UPLINK,99
TEST-SWITCH,25,Reserve,99
TEST-SWITCH,26,Reserve,99
TEST-SWITCH,27,Reserve,99
TEST-SWITCH,28,Reserve,99
```

Here is the content of CSV2:

```
Switch Port,IP Address,Mac Address,Manufactor
17,172.28.7.219,38:91:fb:00:1c:78,Xenox Holding BV
1,10.33.6.10,ec:b1:d7:61:b7:40,Hewlett Packard
9,10.33.6.30,7c:d3:0a:1b:5c:6e,INVENTEC CORPORATION
22,172.28.7.211,08:e6:89:96:f3:ac,Apple Inc.
10,10.33.6.77,a0:8c:fd:14:7c:c5,Hewlett Packard
22,10.33.6.251,34:56:fe:a0:d2:86,Cisco Meraki
24,10.33.6.1,ac:17:c8:5c:74:ac,Cisco Meraki
2,10.33.6.20,60:c7:98:c9:ec:63,Verifone
3,10.33.6.11,ec:b1:d7:61:b7:f6,Hewlett Packard
4,10.33.6.21,60:c7:98:c9:ec:68,Verifone
23,10.33.6.250,34:56:fe:a0:d3:2d,Cisco Meraki
19,172.28.7.224,00:17:55:e8:37:79,GE Security
22,10.33.6.122,14:20:5e:1f:6f:1d,Apple Inc.
23,172.28.7.212,fc:d8:48:88:00:58,Apple Inc.
```

As you can see the header switchport is in both CSV's. I want to create a python script that if csv2 switchport matches csv1 switchport, write csv1 + append the data from csv2, if it not matches, write csv1 + NO IP, NO MAC, NO VENDOR

Any ideas? When i write the output in my for loop like this:

```
if sp == switch_port:
                            vendor = requests.get('https://api.macvendors.com/' + client_item['mac'])
                            vendor = (format(str(vendor.text)))
                            vendor = vendor.replace(",","")
                            time.sleep(1)
                            writer.writerow({csv_headers[0]:name,csv_headers[1]:switch_port,csv_headers[2]:switch_port_name,csv_headers[3]:vlan,csv_headers[4]:ip,csv_headers[5]:mac,csv_headers[6]:vendor})

                        elif sp != switch_port:
                            writer.writerow({csv_headers[0]:name,csv_headers[1]:switch_port,csv_headers[2]:switch_port_name,csv_headers[3]:vlan,csv_headers[4]:'No IP',csv_headers[5]:'No MAC',csv_headers[6]:'No vendor'})
```

I get double entries and the data does not append.

I would like to have my output like this:

```
Switch,Switchport Number,Port Name,VLAN,IP Address,Mac Address,Manufactor
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `csv1 + NO IP, NO MAC, NO VENDOR`, what does that mean?

Comment: It means that the switchport in csv1 has no connected clients, so there is NO IP, NO MAC and no VENDOR. If the switchport in csv1 does have an IP, it matches with the switchport in csv2 and then i need to append the data from csv1 with the data from csv2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a LEFT JOIN, which you can easily achieve by using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html):

```
import pandas as pd

# load tables and unify join key for simplicity
df1 = pd.read_csv("csv1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("csv2.csv")
df2.rename(columns={"Switch Port": "Switchport Number"}, inplace=True)

# merge tables
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=["Switchport Number"], how="left")

# replace NaN values with default strings
default_values = {"IP Address": "NO IP", "Mac Address": "NO MAC", "Manufactor": "NO VENDOR"}
merged_df.fillna(value=default_values, inplace=True)

# write result to file
merged_df.to_csv("csv3.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am reading the pandas documentation, only sometime its hard to understand. Your script works perfectly! Thanks again! I will try to make some sense of the documentation :)

Comment: pandas is very powerful, but confusing at times since there are often multiple ways solving a problem. Have fun looking into it.